# SQL Server table-valued function Parameters were not supplied for the function-

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I keep getting the error : "Parameters were not supplied" for a very simple table-valued function. I cannot figure out what is the issue. I narrowed the function down to :

```
create FUNCTION udf_XX_OddFCST()
    RETURNS @output TABLE (
        articlecode nvarchar(50)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    insert into @output(articlecode) values ('abc');
    RETURN
END
```

So I get the error when executing

```
select * from udf_XX_OddFCST
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

kind regards

Comment: Functions have parameters after them: `FROM udf_XX_OddFCST()`. Also, I really recommend changing the above from a multi-line table-value function to an inline table-value function; they are far faster.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. If I look into the documentation, it should be possible to add zero input parameters. Even if I add dummy parameters I get the same issue. I tried inline table function, but there I could not use dynamic SQL. I would need dynamic SQL to build my statement and return the output as a table,.

Comment: Yes, you can have no parameters, but you still need to include the paranthesis for the parameters. All functions require the parameters be decalred, even if they have none. It's not `SELECT GETDATE;` it's `SELECT GETDATE()`. In your case it's not `udf_XX_OddFCST` it's `udf_XX_OddFCST()`.

Comment: *"I tried inline table function, but there I could not use dynamic SQL."* A multi-line table-value function can't use dynamic SQL either; no functions can. If you need dynamic SQL, you'll need to use a Stored Procedure, which work very differently.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Using the () worked, but I get the message that I cannot use sp_excecutesql. I do know how Stored Procedures work. My goal was actually to use the output of dynamic sql in a table that I could easily query.

Comment: "*but I get the message that I cannot use sp_excecutesql"*. See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65669573/sql-server-table-valued-function-parameters-were-not-supplied-for-the-function?noredirect=1#comment116107550_65669573). Of course, the function you show us doesn't even have `sp_executesql` in it. What we have here is a clear [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use parentheses in your function call :

```
SELECT * FROM udf_XX_OddFCST()
```

however as it has been mentioned in the comments, it would be more simpler and more efficient using iTVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_XX_OddFCST()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (select 'abc' as articlecode)

SELECT * FROM udf_XX_OddFCST()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I cannot use dynamic SQL in a table function, so I will need to find another solution, but thanks again!

Comment: I think you mean hard coded values , anyways that's what you showed us. I answered based on the information you provided,

Comment: yes, and your feedback is greatly appreciated. The fact that I had an answer on this simplified version helped me solve the other issue.

Comment: great , happy I helped